# Can´t shut down Second Windows Form

Tags: windows, forms

I´m working on Visual Studio 2017 (Visual Basic.NET), I just created an app that uses just two windows forms, the first one is a progress bar, when that one gest to 100 % launch the second windows form, but no matter what I can´t close it no by code or by pressing the close button, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: ublic Class Form1
    Dim x As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Start()
        ProgressBar1.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkOrange
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If x < 100 Then
            x = x + 1
            ProgressBar1.Value = x
        Else
            Form2.Show()
            Me.Close()


        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: When I started coding on visual basic.net to jum from one windows from to other I wrote down me.hide(), follow by form2.show...that was the mistake, the first windows form just went under but keeps active that wast the reasin i couldn´t close the window, I changed to Form2.show(),me.close...and that´s it

Answer (score 0):

In Form1

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                base.OnLoad(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

In Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bgWorker.DoWork += BgWorker_DoWork;
            bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;        
            bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bgWorker.ProgressChanged += BgWorker_ProgressChanged;
            bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

        private void BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }

        private void BgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(progressBar1.Maximum >= e.ProgressPercentage)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            }
        }

        private void BgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= 100)    
            {
                if (bgWorker.CancellationPending) 
                {                                  
                    bgWorker.CancelAsync();
                    return;    
                }

                i++;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); 
                bgWorker.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnLoad(e);
            bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```